# Signal R Websockets and multi node servers

Tags: websocket, signalr

I am mapping users to connections as described in the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections so I can find which user's to send messages to.

I was wondering if there is any additional work required for this to work smoothly on multi node servers / load balancing. Im not experienced on the infrastructure side but I'm assuming if there are multi servers spun up, there would be multiple static hashmaps storing the mappings of users to connections - i.e., one for each server.

Would this mean users that have made a connection from their browser to node A will not be able to communicate to users who've connected to node B ?

If this is the case, how would we go about making this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that same link, just below the Introduction section, it discusses 4 different mapping methods:

- The User ID Provider (SignalR 2)
- In-memory storage, such as a dictionary
- SignalR group for each user
- Permanent, external storage, such as a database table or Azure table storage

And after that there is a table that show which of these works in different scenarios. One of those scenarios being "More than one server".

Since it is not mentioned, it depends on which mapping method you are following.

From there, you can check out "scaling out" on the same [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr) you noted which has several methods you can follow depending on what suites your needs. This is where sending messages to clients regardless of which server they connect are handled.